# Itextsharp Paragraph Change indention for second line

Tags: c#, itext, indentation

I want to show some paragraph text with itextsharp as following

```
   "Hello This Is First Line 
second line will start from this X position 
all line coming will be align with second line "
```

any suggestion for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

To indent you need to create a Paragraph and set a TabStop and add the Tab

```
Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
p.AddTabStops(new TabStop(10));
p.Add(new Tab());
```

The value `10` in the TabStop constructor is position of the Left Tab